# ServiceStack no server-side async support

Tags: servicestack

A buddy of mine told me in the past he had looked at ServiceStack.  Said it looked good but that it had no async support so in his book, it's not an option to use this framework (no good if no async) and I have to sorta agree.

Unless ServiceStack has added async, not sure if this is a good choice for me.

It makes me wonder a) is stackoverflow truly using this if there is no async? b) if yes to a, then it obviously must be a highly customized version of it that probably DOES have async?

I am sure someone from stackoverflow can answer this post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Server-side async was added in ServiceStack v4

The [most requested feature](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/4458714-server-side-async-support), Server-side async support has been added where HttpHandlers in ServiceStack now inherit from a common `HttpAsyncTaskHandler` base class that implements `IHttpAsyncHandler`. This lets you return an async Task from your Service in any number of ways as shown in [AsyncTaskTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AsyncTaskTests.cs)

E.g. Services can now have either an object, Task or async Task return types that can return a started or non-started task (which we'll start ourselves). This transition went as smooth as it could where all existing services continuing to work as before and all tests passing.

#### Task based Async in ServiceStack Service Clients

In matching the new server-side async story and now that all projects have been upgraded to .NET 4.0, all Service Clients have been changed to return .NET 4.0 Task's for all async operations so they can be used in C#'s async/await methods. Some examples of Async in action: [AsyncRestClientTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AsyncRestClientTests.cs)

The Async API's also provide a OnDownloadProgress callback which you can tap into to provide a progress indicator in your UI, E.g: [AsyncProgressTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Tests/AsyncProgressTests.cs)

#### Async API's in Http Utils

[Async overloads have also been added to HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils#async-http-utils) which provides a nice API for calling external 3rd Party (i.e. non-ServiceStack) HTTP Services.

---

### Caching provides better performance than Async

Not sure what real-world measurements has led to the conclusion that Async is mandatory for maintaining a high-performance system, given a good caching strategy will provide better performance than Async can. There are a number of high-performance services and websites that doesn't use async, e.g. [YouTube is built with 1M lines of blocking Python to handle 4 Billion views a day](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/3/26/7-years-of-youtube-scalability-lessons-in-30-minutes.html), more recently Disqus posts how they got Django (a heavy Python Web framework) to [scale to 8 billion page views by leveraging HTTP Caching](http://blog.disqus.com/post/62187806135/scaling-django-to-8-billion-page-views). For most multi-threaded sites/services (e.g. .NET/Ruby/Python), blocking IO is the norm, not async - which like all premature optimizations should be measured to calculate if it actually yields any end-user/utilization benefits.

#### StackOverflow uses ASP.NET's Sync MVC Controllers

StackOverflow itself is a ASP.NET MVC Website which uses the standard Synchronous MVC Controllers and employs a good caching strategy that utilizes both local and distributed caching and makes use of ServiceStack's JSON serializer. So even using synchronous MVC controllers [StackOverflow has extremely good server utilization for handling 95M page views/month](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html). StackOverflow [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is what uses ServiceStack and its [RedisMQ support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) for all its BackOffice operations.

Comment: I'm thinking more of the .NET 4.0 async and await commands (server-side async)

Comment: Asynchrony is orthogonal to caching; one is not a replacement for the other. Blocking IO is only the norm because of most languages' lack of continuation passing style (CPS) transformations. Traditionally, non-blocking IO has been more of a hassle than it was worth to implement so naturally there is a lack of research on the topic. Look at nginx's and lighttpd's implementations. I would almost call them ideal examples of non-blocking request-handling state machines. They take a similar approach to what .NET 4.5 does with asynchronous HTTP request serving.

Comment: right so technically ServiceStack does not have async support yet server-side for incoming HttpRequests.  So I guess the answer here is NO.

Comment: The decision to use both async and caching together gives you a powerful tool in your hand.
Saying, cache is better than async makes no sense on certain scenarios.


If you have 5000 different users, caching won't help accessing their different data. However, async would do, making ASP.NET working threads *available* for all of the users as the sql queries are going on.

So yes, added in v4 should not prevent you to add some .NET 4 specific additions (async method alternatives), right?

Comment: @DotNetWise Caching is more often a better performing alternative than async which in most cases alleviates any need and should be considered (and evaluated) before rewriting logic in async. I've updated the answer to reflect that [Server Side async was added in v4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AsyncTaskTests.cs#L216). ProTip: Using `End of Story` has no place in comments which is more likely to prevent anyone wanting to help you in future.

Comment: One use case I encountered where async was the only solution was during the implementation of a high-throughput web API, designed to handle many thousands of simultaneous requests per second on commodity hardware or VMs with shared cores. With blocking calls to the back-end service bus, thread exhaustion was instantaneous and persistent on IIS. As soon as we implemented an async solution using I/O Completion Ports, the service was able to scale appropriately. There was no blocking call implementation that would support enough throughput to make us happy.

Comment: Net zero: thanks for the info on ServiceStack, but the anti-async editorial is dubious and unneeded.