# ServiceStack client in ASP.NET async pages or web handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, servicestack

I've got a call using ServiceStack's PostAsync working, and have wrapped it in Begin / End methods that fire as expected in a debugger. My issue is that this alone won't allow me to use these methods in an ASP.NET async page (2.0) or asynchronous handler, as none of the xxxAsync methods return an IAsyncResult.

Has anyone leveraged a ServiceStack async call in an async page or asynchronous handler, and if so how did you pull it off?

Comment: maybe  this [answer from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902135/servicestack-no-server-side-async-support) is helpful to your problem ?

Comment: Thanks, this is specifically for the client and caching is not an option. We're making several web service requests per second, just trying to avoid queuing of thread requests.

In a pinch I could use httpwebrequest.begin/endgetresponse, but would rather stick to ServiceStack's PostAsync / GetAsync, especially since I know they work outside of the context of IAsyncResult.