# How to wait for all concurrent Tasks to complete in synchronous code .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have the following ServiceStack web service

```
public class RetreadServices : Service
{
    public IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902135/servicestack-no-server-side-async-support

    public async Task<ValidationResponse> Get(RetreadSsnInfoAsync request)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Tenant.SetTenant(request.TenantId);
            return new ValidationResponse { Result = Repository.CannotRetreadSsn(request.Ssn) };                    
        });
    }

    public async Task<ValidationResponse> Get(RetreadEmailInfoAsync request)
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Tenant.SetTenant(request.TenantId);
            return new ValidationResponse { Result = Repository.CannotRetreadEmail(request.Emails) };
        });
    }

    //more methods constructed in the same fashion

}
```

then in a separate class in my application I have this method (based off of code from @StephenCleary)

```
private async Task<ValidationResponse[]> DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync(string tenantId, string[] emails, string ssn)
{
    Task<ValidationResponse>[] tasks =
    {
        ResolveService<RetreadServices>().Get(new RetreadEmailInfoAsync { TenantId = tenantId, Emails = emails }), 
        ResolveService<RetreadServices>().Get(new RetreadSsnInfoAsync { TenantId = tenantId, Ssn = ssn })
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    ValidationResponse[] result = new ValidationResponse[tasks.Length];

    return result;
}
```

and being invoked like this

```
synchronous code...
synchronous code...

var result = DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync(request.TenantId, request.Emails, request.Ssn);

synchronous code...
synchronous code...
```

The goal of all of this is to wait while the tasks process in parallel and hopefully decrease my over-all time... but the DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync needs to block, how do I do that? Then as a bonus, how do I pass the return values back from the individual tasks up and out of the method with the async modifier?

Comment: You can use `Task.WaitAll(Task array)` or see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously

Comment: On a side note, this (`return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>`) is exactly the wrong approach on the server side. It would be more efficient to remove the `async`, `await`, and `StartNew` on the server side. (The client can still be asynchronous even if the server is synchronous).

Comment: @StephenCleary I knew that comment was coming, I have at least 3 tabs open right now where you explain the issues with  StartNew. I've actually changed the code to use TPL.

Comment: @StephenCleary on a side note, what if I did want to do async on the server since we're using IHttpAsyncHandler , how would you construct the server-side code?

Comment: @Stephen: Neither `StartNew` nor `Task.Run` is appropriate here. If you have asynchronous code, then just call it using `await`. If you have synchronous code, then just call it directly. In this case, `StartNew`/`Run` will only add overhead without any benefit.

Answer (score 4):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly.  But don't you just need to add the `await` keyword?

```
synchronous code...
synchronous code...

var result = await DoOperationsConcurrentlyAsync(request.TenantId, request.Emails, request.Ssn);

synchronous code...
synchronous code...
```

**EDIT:** Bonus question: Again, I hope I'm understanding you correctly...

But I would replace this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

ValidationResponse[] result = new ValidationResponse[tasks.Length];

return result;
```

...with simply this:

```
return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

That should work the way you want it.